# UnitTest call /swagger-ui.html results in a 404 for springdoc-openapi

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springfox

I am trying to migrate to springdoc-openapi; Everything runs great except being able to run unit-tests from mvn; The following maven command results in a 404:

- mvn -Dtest=SwaggerUITest test -f TestSwaggerUi -P integration

Intellij has no problem running it, so I suspect that it is a classloading issue.

I have used the code from the example below and just added my unit-test

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

Guthub code:
- https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-springdoc

For the unit-test I added to the pom.xml:
(I use rest-assured to check if the swagger-ui page exists)

```xml
   <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The test itself:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SwaggerUITest extends AbstractRestAssuredSetupClass {

    /**
     * Test successful swagger-UI call
     **/
    @Test
    public void getSwaggerUIPage() {
        givenAnAdministratorIsAuthenticated()
                .contentType(HTML)
                .get("/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/v3/api-docs")
                .then()
                .statusCode(OK.value());
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractRestAssuredSetupClass {

    @Value("${request.logging.enabled:true}")
    private boolean logRequests;
    @Value("${response.logging.enabled:true}")
    private boolean logResponses;
    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Before
    public void setUpRestAssured() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + port;
        RestAssured.config = config().redirect(redirectConfig().followRedirects(false));
        if (logRequests) {
            RestAssured.filters(new RequestLoggingFilter());
        }
        if (logResponses) {
            RestAssured.filters(new ResponseLoggingFilter());
        }
    }

    protected RequestSpecification givenAnAdministratorIsAuthenticated() {
        return RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("user", "user");
    }
}
```

I found also someone that has the same problem: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/99

Unfortunately no solution. I could also go back to springfox. 
Issues like this caused me to migrate: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look, at the sample you are mentioning from baeldung.
We have added it to the demos witht a sample test of the UI. (SwaggerUnitTest). Its passing on travis-CI without any issue.

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/spring-boot-springdoc

You can also have a look at the tests:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-ui/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/ui/app1/SpringDocApp1Test.java

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed after upgrading `springdoc-openapi-ui` to version 1.4.6

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add this lines into you `WebSecurityConfigs`:

```
.antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
```